# Are conceptual questions on topic on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

Most of the time, I see people posting specific problems with code, then a sample, what they've tried, etc.

But what if my question is more of a theoretical nature? Like "Do data structures work in the same way in C and Java?" or "I've already done data structures in C. Do I code them in Java in the same way?"

Are these kind of questions on-topic, or should I ask these in Programmers.SE?

Comment: Future viewers might also find this useful:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144

Comment: see [What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have conceptual questions that are appropriate for the site, yes, but many of them, including the examples you gave, are Too Broad.  Even if the question doesn't contain code, it should still be narrowly scoped such that they can be given a complete, objectively correct answer in a reasonably scoped answer.

Comment: Are these questions Too Broad on Programmers.SE as well? Please include that.

Comment: @cst1992 If your question is Too Broad it wouldn't be on topic on any site.

Comment: I don't use  Programmers.SE  much but presumably questions like this would be more welcome on that site

Comment: @JosephDoggie You presume incorrectly.

Comment: well, to put it the opposite way, it would be much *less* welcome on SO than SE..... as in a math formula w(SO) < w(SE)

Comment: @JosephDoggie this kind questions are _very_ poor fit for Programmers - they tend to be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**